# PyQT5 QtGui doesn't contain QPushbutton

Tags: python, python-import, pyqt5

This is the simple line of code for creating the Button Object

```
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button')
```

and gives out this error

```
        AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QPushbutton'
```

These are my imports

```
        from PyQt5 import QtGui
        from PyQt5 import QtCore
        from PyQt5.QtCore import *
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
        from PyQt5.QtGui import *

        import sys
```

I am running compatible versions of Python(3.5.2)32Bit and PyQt5 32bit
I tried QtGui.QLabel also and no luck.

Comment: does the QtWidgets QPushbutton do the same job?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a capital B?

Comment: @tdelaney With or without the capital B it doesnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyQt5 is not compitible with PyQt4, so it's very unlikely that you'll be able to run a PyQt4 application with PyQt5 without making some changes. For details, see: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html).

As to the specific issue, try:

```
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
```